# Gestures in fullscreen mode

Tags: android, fullscreen, gesture

I have created an Android application for playing videos. These videos are played in fullscreen mode. I'm using this piece of code for enable fullscreen:

```
if (mActivity != null) {
        Window window = mActivity.getWindow();
        View decorView = window.getDecorView();

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
            decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
            );
        } else {
            window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
            window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN);
            decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE);
            mActivity.getActionBar().hide();
        }
        if (hideBottomPanel) {
            mVideoController.smoothHide();
        }
        mIsFullscreenOn = true;            
}
```

Note that minimum Android API for my application is set to 14. Everything works well for me.

Now, I need to implement new feature - the gestures (like swipe left and right) for change position in video (I mean seeking forward and backward; very similar like gestures in PlayMovie application from Google).
I know that I should use GestureOverlayView, GestureLibraries, etc. I have already prepared this feature, but there is some issue.

In case, that my video is in fullscreen mode, the gestures are not detected. Instead of detecting a gesture, a status bar with clock, notifications, etc appeared.

Is there any way how can I achieve my requirements? In other words, is there any way how can I detect gestures in fullscreen mode without showing status bar?

Thanks for any help.

**UPDATE**

For detecting gestures, I have registered listener:

```
gestureOverlayView.addOnGesturePerformedListener(mOnGesturePerformedListener);
```

It looks like this:

```
private GestureOverlayView.OnGesturePerformedListener mOnGesturePerformedListener = new GestureOverlayView.OnGesturePerformedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGesturePerformed(GestureOverlayView overlay, Gesture gesture) {
        ArrayList<Prediction> predictions = mGestureLibrary.recognize(gesture);
        for (Prediction prediction : predictions) {
            if (prediction.score > 1.0) {
                if (prediction.name.equals(SEEK_BACKWARD_GESTURE) && mPlayerIsPrepared) {
                    mPlayer.seekTo(Math.max(mPlayer.getCurrentPosition() - SEEK_SIZE, 0));                        
                } else if (prediction.name.equals(SEEK_FORWARD_GESTURE) && mPlayerIsPrepared) {
                    mPlayer.seekTo(Math.min(mPlayer.getCurrentPosition() + SEEK_SIZE, mPlayer.getDuration()));                       
                }
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, prediction.name);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
};
```

And in `onActivityCreated` I have an initialization of gesture library:

```
mGestureLibrary = GestureLibraries.fromRawResource(mActivity, R.raw.gestures);
```

My code for detecting gestures works fine, but only in "non-fullscreen" mode. So, I think that problem is not directly in code for detecting gestures, but maybe in fullscreen, because in fullscreen gestures are not detected (it is same case as OnClickListener on button for example - in fullscreen, the first touch does not trigger listener, but only show status bar).

**UPDATE 2**

I edited my code for switching between full-screen and "non full-screen" mode. For API19+ I added an `immersive` mode, and for API 16 - 18 I added some other flags. Now my code for full-screen looks like this:

```
if (mActivity != null) {
        Window window = mActivity.getWindow();
        View decorView = window.getDecorView();            
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE);
        } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 16) {
            decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE);
            mActivity.getActionBar().hide();
            window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
            window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN);
        } else {
            window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
            window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN);
            mActivity.getActionBar().hide();
        }            
        mVideoController.smoothHide(CONTROL_PANEL_ANIMATION_DURATION);
        mIsFullscreenOn = true;
```

Last modification is in `Activity`, which contains my `Fragment` for playing.

```
// Flag from API18
window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_OVERSCAN);
```

Now, the gestures works fine in full-screen mode. But there is a problem on API 17 and lower. There is a visible "jump of video" when I switching between full-screen and non full-screen mode. In other words, it is visible that layout has been changed. On API18+ the switch from full-screen to non full-screen is fluent.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's only possible if you use the window flag instead of the system ui flag: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#FLAG_FULLSCREEN
You could do this by using one of the fullscreen themes, like Theme_Holo_NoActionBar_Fullscreen.